# Python join more_itertools.windowed results

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, more-itertools

I have a following problem: I am trying to create so-called "digrams", like this:

If I have a word `foobar`, I want to get a list or a generator like: `["fo", "oo", "ob", "ba", "ar"]`. The perfect function to that is `more_itertools.windowed`. The problem is, it returns tuples, like this:

```
In [1]: from more_itertools import windowed

In [2]: for i in windowed("foobar", 2):
   ...:     print(i)
   ...:
('f', 'o')
('o', 'o')
('o', 'b')
('b', 'a')
('a', 'r')
```

Of course I know I can `.join()` them, so I would have:

```
In [3]: for i in windowed("foobar", 2):
   ...:     print(''.join(i))
   ...:
   ...:
fo
oo
ob
ba
ar
```

I was just wondering if there's a function somewhere in `itertools` or `more_itertools` that I don't see that does exactly that. Or is there a more "pythonic" way of doing this by hand?

Comment: `windowed` seems pretty pythonic to me.

Comment: i'm not sure you need `windowed` here, a `zip(s, s[1:])` works just as well. One way to avoid the tuples is `[s[i:i+2] for i in range(len(s) - 1)]`

Comment: These are also called the q-grams of length 2. I am a fan of q-gram filtration for edit distance similarity search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own version of `widowed` using slicing.

```
def str_widowed(s, n):
    for i in range(len(s) - n + 1):
        yield s[i:i+n]
```

This ensure the yielded type is the same as the input, but no longer accepts non-indexed iterables.

Answer (score 2):

`more_itertools.windowed()` is pythonic.  Consider the `pairwise()` [itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) that also yields tuples:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0, s1), (s1, s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

You can easily replace `windowed()` with `pairwise()` and get common results - a generic solution.

---

Alternatively, you can slice strings by emulating the pairwise principle of zipping duplicate but offset strings:

**Code**

```
s = "foobar"

[a + b for a, b in zip(s, s[1:])]
# ['fo', 'oo', 'ob', 'ba', 'ar']
```